# Implementing C++ as webservice on existing hosts with xml in/output

Tags: java, c++, xml, amazon-web-services, heroku

I realise this might not be an appropriate question, but let me try to formulate is at well as possible given the stackoverflow guidelines.

I want to setup a web service. I currently have a C++ algorithm that takes an xml input and generates a new xml output.

I would like to implement it as an API, so that when users post an xml on a webpage, the get the new xml back.

I realise java is the language to do this, and I could translate the algorithm, yet I was wondering if I could do this with C++ on Amazon servers (or others).

I have been browsing and browsing the internet and I have yet to find an integrated tutorial that combines all of the elements I need. Therefore, if somebody could sketch an outline of the framework/low level technologies I need, this would be really helpful (so I am not asking for just a link to a tutorial, although that would be great).

What I think:

1. Implement the C++ like this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-the-aws-sdk-for-c/
   To be honest, even after programming C and java for years, this seems complicated.
2. Could I use Heroku if I compile it as jni (again, seems complicated)
3. How do I make 1. communicate with xml's? I haven't been able to find anything about that.
4. How do I set up access with an API key. Is this another special service? 
   4b. If I were to I convert this to java in its entirety. How do I communicate the xml files. They aren't structured as SOAP, is this a problem?

Sorry for all my beginner questions. I have been reading everywhere but I am struggling to connect the basic concepts.

Comment: well, we wrote our own http server from scratch because we wanted it to be secure. You could do that, but it's a lot of work. Or you could use one that's already out there. Here's one of many: https://code.facebook.com/posts/1503205539947302/

Comment: You may can exec you c++ programm as shell command from another language web friendly ?

Comment: Ideally that would be possible. But I was thinking of using a host such as amazon. Would they allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To extend what @Antoine said, Apache has the [Common Gateway Interface](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html) that could be useful for this.  To be honest, I haven't written anything in CGI in this decade, but it could be your simplest answer.  Your CGI "script" would live behind Apache and pretty much run on a command line.  To make it work in CGI you will very likely have to modify the code a bit but it can be done.